# Change key of Desfire Card application

Tags: smartcard, contactless-smartcard, pcsc, desfire

I am tried to change a key "00" of a application in a Desfire Card, I understand that the INS is C4, but I received an error, the 7E that is "incorrect length", my command (because I authenticate me with the same 00 key) is:

Command1 = C4 + KeyNo + NewPass + KeyVersion + CRC + PaddingZeros

but, I need a wrapper because my hardware communication:

90 00 00 LengthCommand Command1 00

My command1 is:
80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C8 B6 00 00 00 00 00 00

then my command complete:

90 C4 00 00 25 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C8 B6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

I send the command and received the 7E error. Why?

Comment: Some DESFire commands like the "Change Key" command are **encrypted**, so you need to run an "AES/CBC/NOPADDING" encryption on the command data before sending them to the card. This may help you in finding a way to do so: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/revk/DESFireAES/master/DESFire.pdf . Btw: The encryption and algorithm depends on the existing KeyType for the specific application.